# Special connexion with a node (TikZ)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, node-connections

I want to connect a rectangle with a circular node using an arrow, as in the picture below (to the right).

[image]

The problem is that I have to specify very arbitrary coordinates (e.g. -2.97 in the code below) so that the tip of the arrow is at the right height. This is why I thought to use a node to connect the tip of the arrow to the circle. I obtain, however, what is shown to the left of the picture above... How can I get the desired result (to the right) without specifying a height manually?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper,textwidth=8.5in,textheight=11in]{geometry}
\usepackage{lscape}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\coordinate(A) at (1.5,4);
\coordinate(B) at (2,0.5);
\coordinate(C) at (8,0.5);

\node (C1) at (B) [circle, inner sep=5pt, draw, thick, fill=white] {};
\node (C2) at (C) [circle, inner sep=5pt, draw, thick, fill=white] {};

\foreach \x in {0,1}
\draw [thick, fill=white] ([shift=(A)]6*\x,0) rectangle +(1,-0.35); 

\draw [thick, -{Stealth[length=8pt, width=8pt, inset=2pt]}] (A) ++(0.3,-0.35) -- (C1);
\draw [thick, -{Stealth[length=8pt, width=8pt, inset=2pt]}] (7.5,4) ++(0.3,-0.35) -- +(0,-2.97);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Comment: So... do you want to draw an arrow that stops at the node but is still perpendicular?

Comment: What are you planning on doing with the rectangles? Maybe you can use nodes for the rectangles as well? In that case it's fairly easy

Comment: Alenanno: Yes. But I want the arrow to be shifted to the left relative to the vertical line passing through the center of the circle.

Comment: (C1.north west) worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution using and a rectangular node (and a quick and dirty fill=white). Alenanno's solution is closer to your original code though, so it is probably more useful.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fadings}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate(A) at (1.5,4);
\coordinate(B) at (2,0.5);
\coordinate(C) at (8,0.5);
\node (C2) at (C) [circle, inner sep=5pt, draw, thick, fill=white] {};
\draw [thick, fill=white] ([shift=(A)]6,0) rectangle +(1,-0.35); 
\draw [thick, -{Stealth[length=8pt, width=8pt, inset=2pt]}] (7.5,4) ++(0.3,-0.35) -- +(0,-2.97);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[rectangle,thick,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.35cm,draw=black] (B) at (0,4) {};
\node[yshift=-3.5cm] (C1) at (B) [circle, inner sep=5pt, draw, thick, fill=white] {};
\draw [thick, -{Stealth[length=8pt, width=8pt, inset=2pt]}] (B)  -| (C1.north west); 
\node[rectangle,thick,fill=white,minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.35cm,draw=black] (B) at (0,4) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The code creates the rectangle B twice, the second time to hide part of the drawn arrow (using `fill=white`). I've included your picture for comparison.

[image: Left original, right with nodes]

Answer (score 2):

These are indeed special connections which are not very easy to deal with.

Are these connections only to connect circles with straight lines, you can use the `intersection cs` (or its implicit variant `intersection of`). Of course, you could also use the `intersections` library but then you need to name paths and those path have to actually intersect.
(Due to a bug in the implementation of the calculation of intersections between circles and lines, it is not possible to use the second solution (`solution=2` or `intersection 2 of`). But one can use the direction of the line for this (in our case, just use `y shift=-1`).)

I am using also nodes for the rectangle parts, the `Rectangle=<width>x<height>` key is used to add a rectangle that has the dimensions in the xy coordinate system. (For `circle`s, something similar can be done, for example with the `through` library.)

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fadings,calc}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
  Rectangle/.style args={#1x#2}{
    shape=rectangle,
    /utils/exec=\pgfpointxy{#1}{#2},% in TikZ: (#1,#2)
    minimum width/.expanded=\the\pgf@x,
    minimum height/.expanded=\the\pgf@y}}
\makeatother
\tikzset{
 x shift/.style={shift={(0:#1)}},
 y shift/.style={shift={(90:#1)}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick,
  c/.style={circle, inner sep=5pt, draw, node contents=},
  r/.style={Rectangle=1 x .35, draw, anchor=north west, node contents=},
  myTip/.tip={Stealth[length=8pt, width=8pt, inset=2pt]}
 ]
  \node (C1) at (2,.5)  [c]; \node (C2) at (4,.5)    [c];
  \node (R1) at (1.5,4) [r]; \node (R2) at (2+1.5,4) [r];

  \draw[-myTip] ([x shift=.3]R1.south west) coordinate (aux) --
    (intersection of C1 and aux--{[y shift=1]aux});
  \draw[-myTip] ([x shift=.6]R2.south west) coordinate (aux) --
    (intersection cs: first line={(aux)--([y shift=1]aux)}, second node=C2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

I defined a new coordinate `F` in your example (`A` + the relative coordinates), because it's easier without using relative coordinates like you did, then you can use the following syntax.

```
(F) -- (F|-C1.north);
```

What it does is: start from `F` and then go up to `C1.north` but still perpendicular to `F`. I coloured the arrow red so you see it.

By the way, when possible use nodes including your rectangle. This would be much easier with nodes because I could just use the rectangle node instead of defining a new coordinate.

### Output

[image: figure 1]

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper,textwidth=8.5in,textheight=11in,landscape]{geometry}
%\usepackage{lscape} % use landscape in the geometry package!
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,fadings}

\begin{document}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]

\coordinate(A) at (1.5,4);
\coordinate(B) at (2,0.5);
\coordinate(C) at (8,0.5);
\coordinate(F) at (1.8,3.65);

\node (C1) at (B) [circle, inner sep=5pt, draw, thick, fill=white] {};
\node (C2) at (C) [circle, inner sep=5pt, draw, thick, fill=white] {};

\foreach \x in {0,1}
\draw [thick, fill=white] ([shift=(A)]6*\x,0) rectangle +(1,-0.35); 

\draw [red, thick, -{Stealth[length=8pt, width=8pt, inset=2pt]}] (F) -- (F|-C1.north);
\draw [thick, -{Stealth[length=8pt, width=8pt, inset=2pt]}] (7.5,4) ++(0.3,-0.35) -- +(0,-2.97);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I would want the tip of the arrow to touch the circle, as in the black arrow to the right.

Comment: @Melian Touch how? That would require the circle nodes to possess negative outer sep, because by default the value is positive. Add this to the  circle node options `outer sep=.5pt`, and then add `C1.north west` to the end coordinate of the arrow. The red arrow will touch the node, the black one will not.